Bass Guitar - Thicker String Guage vs Intonation
I changed the strings on my electric bass but I have an intonation problem.  I cannot move the saddle of the lowest string back far enough (away from the nut) to set the intonation correctly.  I changed to a thicker gauge of string because I wanted to try them out.
I've already got my truss rod and action set to feel relatively similar to where it was with the lighter gauge.
Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?
Options that I know would work but are less favorable:

Return back to lighter gauge of string
Move the bridge away from the nut.


It will help to know what guitar it is, with a pic as well. And what gauges the two sets are.

I definitely wouldn’t move the bridge. I’m also curious about the bass and the string gauge. Also maybe your intonation process. If the gauge is really thick, maybe the bass is just not compatible. If the bass is really cheap, maybe that’s part of why. If your intonation process is flawed, maybe you can actually make the intonation correct using the right process. So we need more details to really help.

A pic would be very helpful but one possible easy  fix is to remove the spring on the bolt that holds the saddle in place so you can move the saddle back further.

@JohnBelzaguy - or even shorten that spring. On decent basses, particularly 5 and 6 string, the springs are shortened appropriately. Yours sounds like an answer, given the sparse info.

This question is similar to: Tried Eb alternate tuning but guitar intonation is off and I'm unsure how to fix it. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Tim my original comment I said “or shorten the spring” but in actuality the spring really does nothing to keep the saddle in place once the string is under tension. Removing the spring allows the saddle to go even further back than shortening it. I did not answer because of lack of information in the question.

@Tim I'm not sure if this is a good duplicate. Here the OP says they installed thicker strings, while in the other question a person lowered tuning without changing string gauge.

Please see my answer here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80131/why-is-stratocaster-low-e-string-intonation-at-limit/114087#114087 string not bending properly at the bridge might be actually more likely with thick bass strings than with guitar strings.

Hi folks!  Thanks for all of the feedback!  I will review it and update the question with the extra details.

If your bridge is really installed so far forward that the proper intonation position is out of its range, then the solution would be moving, modifying, or replacing the bridge.  The simplest modification is usually to remove the springs from the bridge, since they often limit the travel of the saddle before anything else.
There is a possible user error- how high is your action?  Higher action requires a flatter intonation position.  It shouldn't be enough to bottom out your saddle, but if your action is way higher than spec, lowering it may bring the intonation requirement back into the adjustment range.
There is also a possible workaround- using a tapered string.  But, I hesitate to recommend tapered strings, because the taper length of most tapered strings is too long for most basses, which drives inharmonicity up and generally sounds pretty bad.
